# Google Maps V3, Directions stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project that uses Google Maps V3. Yesterday everything worked fine but when I ran the application this morning I've recieved the following (and famous) error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'travelMode' of undefined`

I had this error before and this was because I didn't specify the version and he was retrieving the latest version which was causing the error. I specified the version (3.14) and it started working again.

But now it stopped working again and I didn't change anything to the URL retrieving the API. I've noticed also that a property name of the Rectangle changed from `fa` to `ta` (is located in the Bounds property of the Rectangle).

SO the question is: did they change something in version 3.14, although this version is 'Frozen' and shouldn't change anymore.

Comment: *...a property name of the Rectangle changed from fa to ta...*: If you are using internal property names then you have to stop that and use API methods instead of that.

Comment: I've had it already working by changing the property names but good idea to use the native methods. I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: In case someone stumbles up on this thread... It was indeed because I used the propertyNames and because Google Maps is changing their property names (by minification) it's impossible to use the property names. So indeed, use them API methods!!!